# rxJs & angular 4 & restangular: stack errorInterceptors

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, restangular

In my angular 4 app I'm using `ngx-restangular` to handle all server calls. It returns observable as result, and this module has hooks to handle errors (like 401 etc).

But from documentation, i can handle 403 (401) so:

```
  RestangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor((response, subject, responseHandler) => {
    if (response.status === 403) {

      refreshAccesstoken()
      .switchMap(refreshAccesstokenResponse => {
        //If you want to change request or make with it some actions and give the request to the repeatRequest func.
        //Or you can live it empty and request will be the same.

        // update Authorization header
        response.request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + refreshAccesstokenResponse)

        return response.repeatRequest(response.request);
      })
      .subscribe(
        res => responseHandler(res),
        err => subject.error(err)
      );

      return false; // error handled
    }
    return true; // error not handled
  });
```

and this is good for one request, which has broken with 403 error.
how can i stack this calls using rxJs? Becouse now, for example, i have 3 requests, which have 403 and for each this broken request I'm refreshing token - this is not so good, i have to update my token and then repeat all my broken requests. How can I achive this using Observables?

In angular 1 it was pretty easy:

```
Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(function (response, deferred, responseHandler) {
  if (response.status == 403) {
    // send only one request if multiple errors exist
    if (!refreshingIsInProgress) {
      refreshingIsInProgress = AppApi.refreshAccessToken(); // Returns promise
    }


    $q.when(refreshingIsInProgress, function () {
      refreshingIsInProgress = null;

      setHeaders(response.config.headers);

      // repeat request with error
      $http(response.config).then(responseHandler, deferred);
    }, function () {
      refreshingIsInProgress = null;

      $state.go('auth');
    });

    return false; // stop the promise chain
  }

  return true;
});
```

And all was working like a charm. But I'm new to rxJs & angular 4 and I don't have any idea how to achive this with observables and angular 4. Maybe somebody have an idea?

upd!
here is my refreshAccesstoken method

```
const refreshAccesstoken = function () {
  const refreshToken = http.post(environment.apiURL + `/token/refresh`,
    {refreshToken: 'someToken'});
  return refreshToken;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can see of doing this using ngx-restangular is to use the **share** operator. This way you don't have to implement complicated queueing logic. The idea is that if you have 3 requests all of the with a 403 response, they will all hit your interceptor and call your observable. If you share that observable, you will have only one token request for the 3 requests with a broken token.

You just have to use the share operator in your code like so:

```
refreshAccesstoken()
  .share()
  .switchMap(refreshAccesstokenResponse => {
    //If you want to change request or make with it some actions and give the request to the repeatRequest func.
    //Or you can live it empty and request will be the same.

    // update Authorization header
    response.request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + refreshAccesstokenResponse)

    return response.repeatRequest(response.request);
  })
  .subscribe(
    res => responseHandler(res),
    err => subject.error(err)
  );
```

I haven't checked that the code actually works but I have used this approach before for the same use case, but instead of interceptors, I was using the angular HTTP service.

**EDIT to change refreshAccessToken:**

You need to wrap your refreshAccessToken method in a deferred Observable and share it. This way you will reuse the same observable every time.

In the constructor:

```
this.source = Observable.defer(() => {
        return this.refreshAccesstoken();
    }).share();
```

Create another method that will invoke that observable:

```
refreshToken(): Observable<any> {
    return this.source
        .do((data) => {
            this.resolved(data);
        }, error => {
            this.resolved(error);
        });
}
```

**EDIT2**

I have created a [git repository](https://github.com/stely000/ng2-restangular-sandbox) which uses angular2 with restangular.
The scenario is the following:

1. In my app.component I'm making 3 concurrent requests to get a list of orders. When the request has finished, I will log "Orders received".
2. The **orders** endpoint requires an auth token. If one isn't provided it will return a 401.
3. In my app.module I set the base URL to my API only. Because I am not setting the authorization token as well, all of my requests will fail with a 401.
4. When the interceptor code is executed it will set the refresh token, which in my case is hard coded on the request and repeated the request.
5. The observable that returns the token logs "Getting token" each time it is executed.

Here is what I can see in my console:
[image: console logs and requests]

If I remove the share operator I will get the following logs:
[image]
meaning that the observable will be created every time.

In order for this to work, it is important that the source is declared and created in the RestangularConfigFactory. It will essentially become a singleton object and that's what allows the Share operator to work.

**NOTE:**

I created a simple web API hosted locally for this project just because it was faster for me.

**EDIT3:Update to include code to refresh the token:**

```js
@Injectable()
export class TokenRefreshService {
    source: Observable<any>;
    pausedObservable: Observable<any>;
    constructor(
        private authenthicationStore: AuthenticationStore,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationDataService: AuthenticationDataService,
        private http: ObservableHttpService) {
        this.source = Observable.defer(() => {
            return this.postRequest();
        }).share();
    }

    refreshToken(): Observable<any> {
        return this.source
            .do((data) => {
                this.resolved(data);
            }, error => {
                this.resolved(error);
            });
    }

    public shouldRefresh(): boolean {
        if (this.getTime() < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private postRequest(): Observable<any> {
        let authData = this.authenticationDataService.getAuthenticationData();
        if (authData == null) {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
        let data: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        data.append('grant_type', 'refresh_token');

        let obs = this.http.postWithHeaders(
            'token', data, { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
            .map((response) => {
                return this.parseResult(true, response, 'authenticateUserResult');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                let errorMessage = this.rejected(error);
                return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
            });
        return obs;
    }

    private rejected(failure) {
        let authenticateUserResult;
        let response = failure;
        let data = response.json();

        if (response &&
            response.status === 400 &&
            data &&
            data.error &&
            data.error === 'invalid_grant') {

            authenticateUserResult = this.parseResult(false, data, 'error_description');

            return authenticateUserResult;
        } else {
            return failure;
        }
    }

    private parseResult(success, data, resultPropertyName) {

        let authenticateResultParts = data[resultPropertyName].split(':');

        data.result = {
            success: success,
            id: authenticateResultParts[0],
            serverDescription: authenticateResultParts[1]
        };

        return data;
    }

    private resolved(data): void {
        let authenticationResult = data.result;
        if (authenticationResult && authenticationResult.success) {
            let authenticationData = this.createAuthenticationData(data);
            this.authenthicationStore.setUserData(authenticationData);
        } else {
            this.authenthicationStore.clearAll();
            this.router.navigate(['/authenticate/login']);
        }
    }

    private createAuthenticationData(data: any): AuthenticationData {
        let authenticationData = new AuthenticationData();
        authenticationData.access_token = data.access_token;
        authenticationData.token_type = data.token_type;
        authenticationData.username = data.username;
        authenticationData.friendlyName = data.friendlyName;
       
        return authenticationData;
    }

    private getTime(): number {
        return this.getNumberOfSecondsBeforeTokenExpires(this.getTicksUntilExpiration());
    }

    private getTicksUntilExpiration(): number {
        let authData = this.authenticationDataService.getAuthenticationData();
        if (authData) {
            return authData.expire_time;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private getNumberOfSecondsBeforeTokenExpires(ticksWhenTokenExpires: number): number {
        let a;
        if (ticksWhenTokenExpires === 0) {
            a = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 60000);
        } else {
            a = new Date((ticksWhenTokenExpires) * 1000);
        }

        let b = new Date();
        let utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate(), a.getHours(), a.getMinutes(), a.getSeconds());
        let utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate(), b.getHours(), b.getMinutes(), b.getSeconds());

        let timeInSeconds = Math.floor((utc1 - utc2) / 1000);
        return timeInSeconds - 5;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it's calling multiple refresh token action

Comment: also i added my http call)

Comment: I've made an edit that shows how you need to adjust your HTTP call. The initial answer did not work because when you were refreshing the token, you were creating a new observable everytime the method is invoked. Hope this helps.

Comment: `refreshToken(): Observable<any> {` should I use this instead of `refreshAccesstoken() .share()switchMap(refreshAccesstokenResponse => {` ?

Comment: Yes. It's the one you want to share between multiple requests. You would call refreshToken().switchMap(....) in your interceptor

Comment: hm... for me it's not calling anymore with this code: pastebin.com/5TvbTBrQ

Comment: thanks a lot!
but i'm to stupid to get how to combine your code with http call...
here:

`const refreshAccesstoken = function () {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
      obs.next('Bearer nSl2rRuid68C2lV-DH0CQiCq_00r1nkjZQiPW0gG4cNSQaR_JFcucZMIOZsLpe1uyYoRX_LDvEWOpVAameCVEA7g1j45faxpandXKcuJ1Ju5ddI7ObN82HhVViWyPhGEiHepgIOgNVGBwRVNarAzgbRmwW2V5OK593MEpvJ98gCaI7_jmdO_tNC20H_1WQCYmTyujQCeWTDowkAEloS-Yaz1KsSB-0s83OOD8G0mEVc');
    })
      .do((data) => {
        console.log('Getting token');
      }).delay(500);
  };
`
replace here `Observable` with http call :(

Comment: That is a bit more difficult since you can't simply inject the Http service in the factory,or can you ?i will have to check the documentation since its not something that i usually do .

Comment: RestangularModule.forRoot([authService], RestangularConfigFactory), - you can :)
i have now http call... but it's queue isn't right
also: ` it is important that the source is declared and created in the RestangularConfigFactory` - but we can have a lot of factories: so we can have a lot of code-duplicate :)

Comment: Since services in angular are singletons, why not try extracting the logic in a service and then inject it in your factories.

Comment: this won't work since ngx-restangular:
https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular/issues/86
https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular/issues/76

Comment: any news with http?

Comment: Are you asking for the code that requests the refresh token?

Comment: :) thanks, but i know that))) i meant about combining http-refresh token service with `Restangular.setErrorInterceptor`

Comment: In you example, you are using addErrorInterceptor to get the new token? I'm not sure what setErrorInterceptor does.

Comment: addErrorInterceptor is a `interceptor` analogue, which handles each error-request, which is done by restangular

Comment: something isn't clear for me :(
maybe I can share you my code, and for some extra money you can check it?

Comment: Feel free to create a runnable project and send me a link. As long as everything is working and I can just fix the token issue, I am happy to help. I'm not interested in money:), Reputation on the other hand ... :D. I'm saying this because of this because this feels like a different problem.

Comment: I've created a repository with project. You can check all details in this readme:
https://pastebin.com/raw/xBmCFRif
thank's!
also: I removed all .share() etc operators... it's almost a clean code, as it was before. Thanks!

Comment: if you have any troubles with source code, please contact me here :)

Comment: Let me know if my pull request fixed your issue.

Comment: Hi there. I tried it now. Thanks! Almost good, but, unfortunately, still not one refresh-request, but two... Check this video: https://www.screencast.com/t/7BIYBq3Bm24
should be one :)

Comment: I think that's because you are invalidating the refresh token instead of the access token.Try invalidating the access token and see what happens.

Comment: nope... in video i'm invalidating access token. try it :)

Comment: by the way, in your code you don't use pausedObservable: Observable<any>; - what's it for?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in my application and I solved it this way:

> Subscribers keep waiting for source to emit a value and dont do anything till then

We can use this behavior to solve our problem.

What we can do is something like this :

All HTTP Calls :

```
public doSomeHttpCall(params){
   return authService
             .getToken()
             .switchMap(token => httpcall())
}
```

With above code, the HTTP call wont happen until we get the token.

Inside auth service :

```
private token = new BehaviorSubject(null);
public getToken(){
   return this.token
              .filter( t => !!t );
}
```

Since I have a filter for token, if token is `falsy` no HTTP call will be executed. As soon as token gets a good value all the HTTP calls continue to execute.

In your case, if there is a `403` , disable the token by setting it to null. After refresh set it to new token value.

```
private refreshInProgress= false;
public refreshToken(){
   if(refreshInProgress){
      //dont do anything 
      return;
   }
   refreshInProgress = true;
   this.token.next(null);
   // fetch new token 
   this.token.next(newToken);
   refreshInProgress = false;
}
```

A very simple illustration here :

jsbin : https://jsbin.com/mefepipiqu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: i can't use any service with ngx-restangular :(

Comment: You can just have these methods in the same class where you are using `ngx-rectangular` , I used service just for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

My solution involves extending the HTTP service offered by angular and overriding the methods to add the following behaviour:

1. Add retry logic for all of your HTTP calls like so:

```js
post<T>(serviceUrl: string, data: any): Observable<T> {
    return Observable.defer(() => {
        return super.post<T>(serviceUrl, data);
    }).retryWhen((error) => {
        return this.refresh(error);
    });
}
```

2. Throw if the status code is different from 403.Else refresh the token and try again. You will try to do this, let's say 3 times. After that you can just give up :)

```js
refresh(obs: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    return obs
        .switchMap((x: any) => {
            if (x.status === 403) {
                return Observable.of(x);
            }
            return Observable.throw(x);
        })
        .scan((acc, value) => {
            return acc + 1;
        }, 0)
        .takeWhile(acc => acc < 3)
        .flatMap(() => {
            console.log('Token refresh retry');
            return this.tokenRefreshService.refreshToken();
        });
}
```

Comment: i need a solution using ngx-restangular - this is the main trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

RxJs is not silver bullet, and in cases like this it can complicate things even more.

While it may be possible to combine several operators and have if-blocks, retry-blocks within single observable stream, in the end solution will be too complicated, difficult to support, understand and refactor. This is particularly true for http handling.

Comment: what can you advice here?)